# German word for “awesome” sounding like “ga-yeah”?

Tags: single-word-request, listening-comprehension

I have this German friend who taught me some words in German, including how to say *awesome, great* or *really really really good.* But he wasn’t able to tell me how to spell it.

Maybe it’s slang and that’s why I can’t find it online. When he says it, it sounds like *ga-yeah.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. Yes I think it's "geil" not "genial" because if it was the latter I would probably hear the 'n' and it would have a different stress/sound (?) He is quite young so I guess it makes sense that he would use it.

Comment: I also remember him telling me that it's not polite to use it especially with someone who's not close to you. (Like "le-kah" which he told me means "yummy" but you can't use it with just anyone) He told me to use it with friends. I also remember him using it like, "Du hast einen geilen arsch". So I guess using "geil" instead of "genial" makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also he says it like "geiel", with two syllables. Like when he used "geilen", same, two syllables.

Comment: If it is "geil" he says it like "gah-yell". Which makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 8):

I would imagine that the word mentioned by your friend is “geil”. In proper German it means “sexually aroused”, but in modern youth-speak it has become a vague term of approbation.

Comment: I'd like to add that you should NOT use it as awesome. I hear people doing it constantly and in 50% of the cases it sounds totally out of place. For example with people. "Maria ist echt geil"... that does not mean that she's awesome.

Comment: I second that. A more emphaszed form of "geil" is pronounced in a way that Germans would write "geiel" (pronounced "guy-ell", with stress on both syllables), which seems closer to what you heard. You won't find it in proper written German, though, only in places like http://www.smsvongesternnacht.de/sms2892 or https://de-de.facebook.com/desgeiel

Comment: You omitted another meaning: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geil#Bedeutung2a

Comment: Yes, excersize caution when using it as a non-native. For natives, it's no problem, they'll realise when it's out of place. A colleague of mine used it so often that her *Doktorhut* was decorated with *Is gaaail!* and *Gei-jel!*

Comment: @Emanuel: It does mean that she's awesome, but only in a very special sense and Maria would likely disapprove if too many people talked about it … Nudge, nudge.

Comment: @Emanuel I agree. When I was studying German (12 years ago at University), we were told about the classical meaning (sexually aroused or horny), but in "every day use", it was much closer to the way we've come to use the word "cool" in English.

Comment: @mbm29414: which will lead to replacing "geil" by "cool" (or something else I bet) in the next generation kids - at least in the school my kids go to "geil" already became old-fashioned parent's speek :)

Comment: You forgot another meaning of »geil« with I believe to be older than »horny« or »cool«: In Austria you use this word to describe food that is fat and sweet: »Eine geile Torte« = »a fat and sweet cake«. »Eine geile Creme« = »a fat and sweet cream«. A Cream or that part of a cake that is *geil* has the texture of butter or of pudding (*pudding* in american English, not the British *pudding*), so it is not made of dough.

Comment: In 1986 Bruce and Bongo (two britisch pop-musicians) visited Germany and discovered the word »geil«. They liked the word so much that they made a song form it (»Geil«). It became number 1 in German and Austrian pop-charts, and #7 in Switzerland. In Germany it was 15 weeks on number 1, in Austria 14 weeks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_P3uwRiimo

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. For the history of the word see here: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=geil. In Old High German “geil” means ‘übermütig, überheblich, erhoben’.

Comment: @fdb: Und noch ein Deutsch-Wörterbuch, das wieder nur ein Deutschland-Wörterbuch ist. Die von mir beschriebene Bedeutung »fett und süß«, die in Österreich gängig ist, fehlt nämlich im DWDS. (Siehe Nr. 5 hier: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geil und Nr. 1 hier: http://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/geil )

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. In diesem Sinne  Grimm & Grimm & alii DWB, Bedeutung 5e.

Answer (score 2):

It could also have been "genial" which used to be the proper attribute of people like Einstein or Mozart and their works:

> Die genialen Erkenntnisse Albert Einsteins führten die Physik in ein neues Zeitalter.

...but has somehow deteriorated, as nowadays it is likely to describe any experience from exceptional to significantly above average:

> Deine Suppe ist genial. Gibst du mir das Rezept?
>
> Genial, dass ich bei dem schönen Wetter einen Tag frei habe.

However, you would rather not call a woman "genial" if you think she's awesome, but some might choose to use it that way, too.

Others have come down, so it seems, to use it even for minor achievements like not leaving with wet pants after a visit in the bathroom (but you shouldn't take that last one literally :-).

Comment: "any above-average" - IMHO that's too weak. Even in today's usage, "genial" still carries a sense of uniqueness. "Deine Suppe ist genial." is a much stronger praise than something like "Deine Suppe schmeckt sehr gut." or "Deine Suppe würde ich gerne wieder essen."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das stimmt, doch das Spektrum ist sehr breit, und Beispiele wie das zweite hört man mittlerweile auch ziemlich oft. Ich habe es etwas angepasst.

Comment: I really do not see how an English speaker could have heard "genial" as "ga-yeah".

Comment: @fdb That is equally true for "geil", I would say, and depends on how it is pronounced. We do not know if that friend had a special dialect, slang, or accent. By the way, as it was something like "geiel", as we now got to know, this is pretty close to "ge-ial" if you drop or suppress the "n" which seemed to have been indicated by the hyphen.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... it's close in spelling but in sound it's not really.  (I'll not use IPA) "guy-elle" vs. "gue ya'll" or in German letters "gaiel" vs. "geial" The first syllable has a different vowel sound, as does the second. "ga-yeah" clearly matches the pattern of "geil", not the one of "genial", also considering where the main stress is "GEI-el" vs. "ge-IAL"

Comment: @Emanuel Now that we know, it looks that way. But the effect described by and named after the British psychologist Harry McGurk (see http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4091305/ or http://www.faculty.ucr.edu/~rosenblu/VSMcGurk.html) shows us that the result may be misleading if somebody tries to make sense of what he doesn't fully comprehend phonetically or doesn't recognize as a word. So it seemed reasonable to consider an alternative.

Comment: McGurk actually tells us that the visual cue can override the audio cue and it doesn't need to be a foreign language at all to be mislead ;). Anyway, but I'm not criticizing the alternative. It's fine. I just didn't want to leave the "pretty close" standing without a comment.

Answer (score -3):

It's hard to see how it could be *geil* if your friend didn't know how to spell it. I'm going to suggest the word could have been *umgeheuer* and he just said it fast.

And that's a word someone might not know how to spell.

Comment: The word "umgeheuer" does not exist. Maybe you mean "ungeheuer"? But that doesn't mean "awesome", more like "terribly", as a modifier of another adjective. I fully agree with your initial statement, though, that there could be any doubt about how to spell "geil".